# nio FileChannel.transferFrom transferring 0?

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to use NIO to assemble a file out of several smaller files, using transferFrom.

The call to transferFrom returns 0. No exception. Nothing done to turn on synchronous behavior.

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
    FileChannel fileBeingAssembled = fos.channel();
    int progressiveOffset = 4096;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tmpT5);
    FileChannel channel = fis.getChannel();
    channel.position(0);
    int thisItemLength = (int)channel.size();
    LOG.info("Writing " + tag + " at " + progressiveOffset + " length " + thisItemLength);
    fileBeingAssembled.position(progressiveOffset);
    long x = fileBeingAssembled.transferFrom(channel, progressiveOffset, thisItemLength);
    LOG.info("transferred " + x);
    progressiveOffset += thisItemLength;
```

An example log:

```
4409 [main] INFO  com.basistech.seg.writing.ModelOutputTask  - available 1856216
4409 [main] INFO  com.basistech.seg.writing.ModelOutputTask  - Writing word at 15024620 length 1856216
4419 [main] INFO  com.basistech.seg.writing.ModelOutputTask  - transferred 0
```

Comment: What was the output of the first log statement?

Comment: @skaffman could it be that it doesn't deal with sparse files?

Comment: Hmm. `progressiveOffset` is set to 4096, and never changed (until after the transferFrom()), yet your log statements have it printing 15024620. I suspect that there is a missing loop here somewhere?

Comment: @Paul Wagland
I did not paste an entire wall of code. Yes, I clipped from the log after the first write.

Comment: No problems... I was originally thinking that it might be something in the loop that might have been causing the issue, however it turns out that it wasn't ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most obvious answers are:

1. That tmpT5 points to a zero byte file, or
2. That the file pointed to by path is less than 4096 bytes long.

From the [transferFrom](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long)) docs:

> If the given position is greater than the file's current size then no bytes are transferred.

Comment: Oh, gosh. I read that three times and got tangled up between the two files. Yes, I was trying to create a sparse file by pointing transferFrom out past the end.